# Handle rtl/ltr in react native apps

Tags: mobile, react-native

I have a react-native app that I tested on a virtual device on my pc.
When I tried it on my phone I noticed that the direction is not set and that it is inheriting it from the device.
I couldn't find anything online regarding how to set the direction of the app.
How can I do it?

Comment: what direction? you mean navigation?

Comment: I mean rtl/ltr.

Comment: Like this? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html

Comment: I read it, and the way I understood it is that this *allows* you to use rtl but does not flip the app entirely. Did I understand wrong?